# error:out of memory error in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write a  matlab code for image morphing . I have to prewarp the images first , i have used imwarp function with the tform as follows ,
the code is ,

```
function []= min_view_morphing(im1,im2)

F = findfundmat(im1,im2)

[ H1, H2 ] = computeH1H2( F )

 H1(:,3)=0;H1(3,:)=0; H1(3,3)=1;
 H2(:,3)=0;H2(3,:)=0; H2(3,3)=1;

inH1=inv(H1);
inH2=inv(H2);

% t_aff1=maketform('projective',real(inH1));
% t_aff2=maketform('projective',real(inH2));
% 
% imw1=imtransform(im2double(im1),t_aff1,'FillValues',.3);
% figure,imshow(imw1);
% imw2=imtransform(im2double(im2),t_aff2,'FillValues',.3);
% figure,imshow(w2);


H1=affine2d(inH1);
H2=affine2d(inH2);

imw1=imwarp(im1,H1);
imw2=imwarp(im2,H2);
figure,imshow(imw1);
figure,imshow(imw2);
```

every time i run this i get an out of memory error no matter how small image size i use , and it happens only for the second image only while both H1 and H2 are 3 cross 3 matrices . any solutions ??

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is not the right site for Matlab questions, I'm afraid.

Comment: Maybe this should be migrated to http://math.stackexchange.com (I can’t choose this site while voting to close, I had our meta site as the only option …)